# Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' not found

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-assembly

I'm currently facing an issue with ASP.NET Core targeting the framework 4.6.1.

> Cannot define a class or member that utilizes 'dynamic' because the compiler required type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.DynamicAttribute' cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?
>   +
>       public class _Views_Home_Index_cshtml : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage
>   Predefined type 'System.Boolean' is not defined or imported
>   +
>       public class _Views_Home_Index_cshtml : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage
>   The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>   +
>       public class _Views_Home_Index_cshtml : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage
>   The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
>   +
>           public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.IModelExpressionProvider ModelExpressionProvider { get; private set; }
>   Predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported
>   +
>           public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.IModelExpressionProvider ModelExpressionProvider { get; private set; }
>   Predefined type 'System.Void' is not defined or imported
>   +
>           public Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.IModelExpressionProvider ModelExpressionProvider { get; private set; }
>   The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

[Here the references](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OirHm.png)

The project is on bitbucket and when my teammate pull the project he doesn't facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the Microsoft.CSharp dll from a .NET 4.6.1 project for dynamic to work.